# How to have one custom field open one or more other fields in a frontend form?

Tags: custom-fields

I need to have a checkbox or yes/no radio field that opens 'Preferred Language field when value=1 or affirmative choice. How is this done?

A more exact use-case: To choose Language Interpretation:
Custom Field: Language Interpretation (Please choose): Yes | No

1. If No, then nothing further appears, move to next step in process flow.
2. If Yes, then Preferred Language menu (system field) appears to choose language and that entry is amended to Contact record.

Answer (score 1):

I both D7 and D8 you would use Conditionals to show/hide fields.
Any field can be hidden/shown -> here's an example of a checkbox which when checked shows First and Last Name

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, Karin, but I am using Joomla. Is there not a function for this native to Civi? For instance, in a contribution form, if "Pay by check" and a payment processor is active two radio buttons appear. If payment processor is selected, the credit card fields appear. If 'Pay by check' is selected, the CC form disappears.

Essentially, 'if x=1 show field' or 'if x=0 do not show field'

Comment: On Drupal a site builder can do - on Joomla you need a Developer. On Joomla you would probably have to copy the civicrm tpl and then make edits to edit (add checkbox and javascript).

Comment: PS - question was originally labeled webform-civicrm; I've removed the label.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that tag was code for something specific.

Comment: No problem - it references webform-civicrm module.

Comment: So, maybe if I give a more exact use-case: To choose Language Interpretation:  
  
1. Field: Language Interpretation (Please choose)    Yes   No  
  
   
If No, then nothing further, move to next step in process flow.  
If Yes, then Preferred Language system field appears so that entry is amended to Contact record.

Comment: More clarity: So, maybe if I give a more exact use-case: To choose Language Interpretation: 
Field: Language Interpretation (Please choose) Yes No 
1. If No, then nothing further, move to next step in process flow. 
2. If Yes, then Preferred Language system field (menu) appears to choose language and that entry is amended to Contact record.